# How to search/filter in CP by date range?

Tags: control-panel, search, datetime, filter

Is there a way in the control panel to list all entries with a date field between two dates? For example, last updated between 12/16/2019 and 2/15/2020.

Interested in doing this for both automatic date fields (created, updated, postDate) and custom.